# Why can't I write to this pipe?

Tags: pipe, posix

I followed the steps in the accepted answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process

However I get this

```
root@ca:/home/kali# echo blah > /tmp/fifo
bash: /tmp/fifo: Permission denied
```

So even if I am root and I chmoded 777 anyway the file, I can't write to it to, Why ?

Comment: See [this question on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503111/108618). What is the output of `sudo cat /proc/sys/fs/protected_fifos`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see, the file has to be owned by the writer if it is inside this directory ? so better use another directory ?

Comment: Instead of asking me, just try in another directory and see.

Comment: why are you asking about a question on a different stackexchange site here, instead of there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's easy to mix these two sites since they are overlapping on unix topics

Comment: yes, but you've specifically referred to a question on that other side, with a question that's specifically about the topic of that other site, whilst also having an account on the other site!